# spring saml extension support for spring 5

Tags: spring-saml

I am new to spring SAML world, I need to implement SSO in my application (SP).
My application is currently on spring 5.04 version and is using spring security 5.0.3.

Is spring SAML project supporting spring 5 now?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the next release will support it. There are reports of people using Spring 5 with minor issues (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/236)